# Catalan number problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have a dynamic formula to calculate numbers of the Catalan sequence length-N, the formula: $$f_{i, j} = f_{i - 1, j - 1} + f_{i - 1, j + 1}, f_{0, 0} = 1$$
in that: $i$ is the current length, $j$ is the value of the catalan number at position $i$
How can I calculate the number $f_{i, j}$ faster ? Is there any formula for that ?

Comment: ?? Catalan numbers don't have two parameters.

Comment: @darij, it seems to be a generalisation. $f_{2n,0}$ is the $n$th Catalan number.

Comment: $f_{i,j}$=number of mountain ranges where each step is one unit up or down, all strps end at or above ground level, there are $i$ total steps and a net rise of $j$ steps.  Catalan numbers have $2n$ total steps and a net elevation of zero; nonzero numbers possible only if total steps and net rise have the same parity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with questions like this, it's always worth generating a few terms and searching OEIS. Searching for the $n=8$ row $$\begin{matrix}14 & 0 & 28 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}$$ I find [A053121](//oeis.org/A053121) which includes such notes as

> $a(n, m) = a(n-1, m-1) + a(n-1, m+1)$ if $n > 0$ and $m \ge 0$, $a(0, 0)=1$, $a(0, m)=0$ if $m > 0$, $a(n, m)=0$ if $m < 0$. - Henry Bottomley, Jan 25 2001

(so it's the right sequence) and

> $$a(n, m) = \begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{if } n<m \textrm{ or } n-m \textrm{ odd} \\
> \frac{m+1}{n+1} \binom{n+1}{\frac12(n-m)} & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$